# File explorer hangs when right clicking mp4 files?

Tags: windows-explorer, freeze, mp4

Right-clicking Mp4s in file explorer freezes the window. A temporary fix is a restart until I right-click another MP4 file.

I've tried cmd commands:

Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth

Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth

Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

sfc /SCANNOW

and running multiple malware scans.

Anyone have a fix for this problem?

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: These commands won't help you.  You are experiencing what is called a "shell extension" which is a DLL that runs in the explorer's process space.  If you go to HKCR\.mp4, look at the (Default) entry, then lookup HKCR\(whatever_you_found) and hunt around the shell entries.  You can use [this tool](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) to view the registered extensions on your system.  Look for 3rd party crap dealing with video files and I bet you will find your culprit.

Comment: Since you have run DISM and SFC, I suggest you try a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link. Start with the option to Keep Everything.

Comment: @harrymc yes, this problem persists when booting in safe mode.

Its also gotten much worse. Right-clicking any file in explorer now crashes the window.

Comment: For more information, when you right click a file, windows looks to the registry to determine what to show.  It then loads code from DLLs and asks them what to display for each and every extension.  If one of those extensions hangs, then the explorer hangs. period.  @John suggestion will fix the problem and reset the handler (HKCR\.mp4) to the original so it will probably fix the problem.. but if you really want to know what broke your stuff, you will have to figure it out for yourself using the registry and shell extension tool.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas The issue has gotten much worse, and now applies to all files.

Comment: Then I would agree with @John 100% :)  .. He is no dummy. :) .. that would be the easiest way out of this mess.. you are probably looking at something messing with HKCR\\* (aka EVERYTHING).  It still probably is not something Microsoft broke but a 3rd party thingamajigger you installed.

Comment: The problem will not go away after a repair install, as this will not delete the bad third-party handler(s) from the registry. In case this is caused by a virus/infection, run deep scans by several well-known antivirus products. If this is not fixed, you might need to reinstall Windows from scratch. Before all, backup your data.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I have ShellExView (the tool you suggested) open right now. When sorting by extensions that do not originate from Microsoft, I only see ones by WinRAR, Nvidia, Malwarebytes, Apple, and Notepad++. Everything else is from Microsoft. Is there something I am missing? How can I see extensions that specifically deal with HKCR\?

Comment: @harrymc This problem only seemed to arise today, and I have not downloaded anything as of late. How do I view all third-party registry handlers?

Comment: The problem will not go away after a repair install,   <-- It depends on the specific error. Repair Install has fixed shell context issues for me, but it may not work for everyone.

Comment: @ Señor CMasMas:   Then I would agree with @John 100% :) .. He is no dummy. :) -<-- Thank you!

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: Update,

The issue seems to be resolved. I deleted a few external programs, and now files are once again responsive to right-clicking. Thank you to everyone who replied!